# Button rearranged without if statement JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, onclick

I am trying to make a button that clicks multiple times with scrolls and highlights. However, I believe I read somewhere that a function (or for loop) does not allow an If statement inside the brackets (from my previous code). Mainly, I do not know how to make the button click multiple times and the extra details of scrolling and highlighting. How should I go about this situation?

The code still does not work maybe I am not correctly typing them in order?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
    if (x == q) {
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.innerHTML = "Next";
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        body.appendChild(button);
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
           return document.getElementById(x).scrollIntoView(true);
        });
        $('body').text().highlight(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that I corrected a syntax error in your code, namely the second closing bracket after `document.getElementById(x).scrollIntoView(true);`. Just to be sure that's not the problem in your code

Comment: You most certainly CAN use an `if` statement within a `for` loop. You are misspelling `appendChild`, by the way.  That could be part of your problem.

Comment: I corrected it. It still does not work.